Redirect not working after login with Microsoft Azure
I'm triying to authenticate with Microsoft active directory with aad_auth package (v.1.0.1)
This is my logic to login:
final Config config = Config(
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/",
  tenant: '*****',
  clientId: '*****',
  scope: 'openid profile',
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  clientSecret: '*****',
);

final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);

config.webUseRedirect = true;
final result = await oauth.login();

This logic show Microsoft login flow correctly, but after enter the password and accept, app shows this web page:

In Azure authentication configuration I set up a SPA.
Any ideas?

Can you share your complete code in the question or can you share the GitHub repo?

@DasariKamali this is all the code that I have implemented for the authentication. No additional configuration is needed.

check this doc.

@DasariKamali I solved the problem with this documentation before check your response :D. Anyway, thanks for your help. The solution was create a new platform (in this case an Android platform) and follow the doc instructions.
